# How to pass response data from server to $scope in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have controller in my project, the controller has a method that takes data  from login input and sends it on server. Also I have an $http service with .then promise which returns me User's data from database. Everything is working correctly,but I can not pass response data to $scope. For example I want to greet authorized user like "Welcome,Username", but response data is not passing to $scope in template. Here`s my code:

auth.controller.js:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("MainModule")
        .controller("AuthCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.login = function () {
                    var loginData = {
                        email: $scope.log_email,
                        password: $scope.log_password
                    };

                    console.log(loginData);

                    $http.post('/login', loginData)

                        .then(function onSuccess(response) {

                            console.log(response.data.first_name);
                            $scope.first_name = response.data.first_name;


                        });
                    };


        });

})();
```

And template file:

header.html:

```
<div ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
<h3>Wellcome</h3> <span>{{first_name}}</span>
</div>
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could you just add `$scope.first_name = '';` at the top of your controller function body and if that will fix it? If not, could you try and use something like `$scope.userData.first_name` in your implementation?

Comment: Are you switching views after login and have multiple instances of `ng-controller="AuthCtrl"`?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not switching views after login, just add information in header if user is authorized, but I have  multiple instances of ng-controller="AuthCtrl". One in Auth form, another in header template file.

Comment: @eminlala, thanks  bro. It's still not working. I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Then you need a service to store that user data. Each instance of `ng-controller` creates a new instance of `AuthCtrl`

Comment: Are `console.log(loginData);` and `console.log(response.data.first_name);` printing the expected results?

Comment: Are you using the ng-app directive?